# How do web servers process multiple connections?

Tags: http, sockets, request, webserver

I'm new to web development and am trying to understand the way web servers handle multiple connections/requests. I understand that incoming HTTP requests get handled via sockets. A new request has a unique socket (SRC-IP SRC-PORT DEST-IP DEST-PORT). But what happens after a socket is created?

1. How is the HTTP response prepared and sent for all the incoming requests?
2. Is this process handled in synchronous or asynchronous manner?
3. Can web servers be multi-threaded? Or are there multiple processes that get created? Or a combination of both?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Rather, it is about how web servers work.

Comment: Stephen could you please help answer the question instead? Aren't we here to share knowledge?